# How to say "One of these" and three other mini phrases?

Tags: translation, mandarin

I'm very glad I found this website. Just a few months ago I've started learning Mandarin Chinese by myself and right now I'm in Sichuan. I try applying my little knowledge in daily life, but it's not easy ...also of course because they don't speak "proper" Mandarin here, but their craaazy dialect instead ...I'm trying anyways :)
A few things I'd like to know but was not able to find in dictionaries / through Google:

Let's say there's a fruit vendor and I want to tell her/him that I'd like **"one of these"** ...so far I've said sth like "这个。。。一个“ - and felt completely stupid doing so. Please help me say it propberly!

Same situation, but I want a bigger/smaller fruit of what he/she's holding in their hand. sth like **"a bigger/smaller one, please"**

When at a shop, asking for a specific item - **"Do you have...?"**
Could I say 这里有。。。吗？ and/or does even the literal translation 你们有。。。吗？ make sense?

and finally: **"I only speak a tiny bit Chinese."**

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not stupid at all. I think they can understand what you are saying.

If you want only one, you could say `这个来一个` ,  `我要一个这个`, or `给我称一个这个`, pointing to the fruits you want to buy. And you could add `只要一个` to emphasize that you need only one.

If you want a smaller/bigger one, you could say `我想要个小/大一点的。` or `能换个小/大一点的吗？`

`这里有...吗？` or `你们有...吗？` are both okay.

Comment: You made a typo, it should be "秤", not "称"

Comment: @thinwa 称(chēng) here is a verb, `to weigh`.

Comment: OMG. I just noticed that I've misuse "秤" as verb for many years...

Answer (score 1):

ElpieKay's answer seems fine to me apart from not answering the last part of the the question (I only speak a tiny bit Chinese"). For that, I propose:

我不太会说中文 (Wǒ bú tài huì shuō Zhōngwén)

(≈ "I can't really speak Chinese")